# Is there a functional form of a function like foreach over an array that yields all pairs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Sorry about the convoluted title, but I hope the following description makes this clearer.

I am currently learning the joys of functional programming in Javascript, using Ramda as my functional library of choice. I have an array which I would like to iterate over in a manner similar way to foreach. However, I would like my anonymous function to be passed all possible pairs from the  original array. So in effect, a matrix is formed where by each axis of the matrix to be represented by the contents of the array:

if I have an array with ["a", "b", "c"] then there are in total 9 combinations of pairs; if I take away each element being paired with itself (which could be implemented by a filter, I guess), there are just 6. But if reduce this again, by not getting called back for the reverse pairs, there are just 3.

So my function would be passed back the following pairs:

```
  "a", "b"
  "a", "c"
  "b", "c"
```

Is there a functional form of this in Ramda or anything other functional library that can do this? It is generic functionality, but I don't know what the 'name' of this functionality would be; perhaps forEachYieldUniquePair. I would like to know of an idiomatic way to do this before I implement it myself, thanks.

Comment: _re in total 9 combinations of pairs;_ - it includes repetitions and order, i.e. `aa, ab, ba... `?

Comment: Why would you need a library function for this? `arr.reduce((acc, letter, index, all) => acc.concat(all.slice(index + 1).map(x => [letter, x])), [])`

Comment: There are a few techniques [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, it generates combinations (3 pairs), he seems to be interested in permutations with repetition

Comment: @Maximus I might be wrong but it seems he is asking  for unique pairs.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, he said `9` pairs, that's why I clarified in the comment

Comment: @Maximus Reread the question carefully "So my function would be passed back the following pairs:" following by 3 **unique** pairs.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, yeah, confusing phrasing... two nested loops would produce unique combinations

Comment: Although Ramda has [`xprod`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#xprod), which gets you part of the way there, I agree with Yury that there is no need for the library to do this.

Comment: Thanks Yury, you got it spot on. I just thought there might be a generic function to do this, particularly in Ramda.  Still getting my head round functional approach to algorithm design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Yury for this correct answer:

arr.reduce((acc, letter, index, all) => acc.concat(all.slice(index + 1).map(x => [letter, x])), [])